# Design a game similar to Lightsout

Tags: java, android

I am design a game similar to lights out in android where user can press any button from a given 5*5 grid. Assume we have only 2*2 grid to understand easily. So when user press a button then the button (up,right,left,down) and itself button will be toggle(if on then off if off the on). Also I want to change color of Button (if Green then black if black then green) GREEN=ON and BLACK=OFF.

So logic I am thinking is on each button press(OnClick).

```
if(button1 is pressed)
then if(button1==ON) then button1=OFF else button1=ON ;
if(button1==ON) then GREEN else BLACK ;
if(button2==ON) then button2=OFF else button2=ON;
if(button2==ON) then GREEN else BLACK ;
if(button3==ON) then button3=OFF else button3=ON;
if(button3==ON) then GREEN else BLACK ;

similarly for button 4
if(button4 is pressed)
then if(button4==ON) then button4=OFF else button4=ON ;
if(button1==ON) then GREEN else BLACK ;
if(button2==ON) then button2=OFF else button2=ON;
if(button2==ON) then GREEN else BLACK ;
if(button3==ON) then button3=OFF else button3=ON;
if(button3==ON) then GREEN else BLACK ;

similarly for all
```

But it is not dynamic So If i change a grid to 5*5 then I have to change to logic again.

Did any body have any better idea than above dumb idea? Also should be dynamic such that I can also work 6*6 grid ?

Thanks

Comment: I would implement two methods toggleRowColor, toggleColColor which set the color of a whole row/column respectively. At least that's how the original game is working if I remember correctly. These two methods should simplify things, I guess.

Comment: What is lightsout?  Can you clarify what the program is supposed to do in the 5x5 and 6x6 cases?

Comment: @DavidWallace this link will clarify http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game) http://www.neok12.com/games/lights-out/lights-out.htm

Answer (score 3):

You should have a model that stores the state of each light in a 2D array of booleans.  So these will be instance methods of your `LightsOut` class.

```
public static final int GRID_SIZE = 5;
boolean[][] lights = new boolean[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
```

Then you should have a method for switching a light on or off, but only if the co-ordinates given are valid.

```
public void toggleLight(int row, int column) {
    if (row >= 0 && row < GRID_SIZE && column >= 0 && column < GRID_SIZE) {
        lights[row][column] = ! lights[row][column];
    }
}
```

You'll need a method for processing the actual click, which might look something like this.

```
public void click(int row, int column) {
    toggleLight(row, column);
    toggleLight(row + 1, column);
    toggleLight(row - 1, column);
    toggleLight(row, column + 1);
    toggleLight(row, column - 1);
}
```

So that's the model.  Then you'll want to build a view on top of that, to actually detect the clicks, show the lights, work out what's green and what's black, and so on.

Comment: awesome. neat and clean

Answer (score 0):

Some things that can make this task a bit easier:

- Set the button names as meaningful row/column names. This way, if button (1,1) is pressed, you would need to check buttons (1,1),(1,2),(2,1), and so on. This way you can dinamically check for all adjacent buttons by creating a method to check the previous and next square on the row/column.
- Instead of checking if the button is on and then assigning on or off (as this makes your program a bit unreadable), you could simply assign on and off to true/false and do `button = !button`. This makes so that the logic value of the button variable is inverted.

Comment: what about the color ? What you said make sense it terms of ON and OFF.

Comment: You could assign the colour to a square depending on the boolean reading (e.g. assign to all squares green if true or black if false)